# NativeIoException:io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException recvAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

I am trying to find the solution for below error which occurs in our Appdynamics logs when we perform load testing with Jmeter for 5tps. I am using spring cloud gateway 2.7.8 and netty version - 4.1.87.Final for routing purpose. The same error we do not see in our kubernetes logs or in Kibana logs. I am not able to trace from where the logs is coming up.

`NativeIoException:io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException recvAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer Error capture limit has been reached, this stack trace is truncated.`

Can someone help me understand why this error is occurring ?

Answer (score 0):

AppDynamics limits the number of registered error types (based on error-logging events, exception chains, and so on) to 4000. It maintains statistics only for registered error types.

Reaching the limit generates the CONTROLLER_ERROR_ADD_REG_LIMIT_REACHED event. While it is possible to increase the limit, we recommend refining the default error detection rules to reduce the number of error registrations to have the error you are not interested in capturing ignored.

https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/application-monitoring/troubleshooting-applications/errors-and-exceptions#id-.ErrorsandExceptionsv22.1-ErrorandExceptionLimits